# Repeated Class Definition In For Loop For Backend/Typing Support

Tags: loops, class, backend, typing

I have the same class called `Class` which needs backend support for `{torch, numpy}` and I want the class functions to be type supported `{Torch, Numpy}`. Example

---

```
# Imports
import numpy as np
from numpy.typing import NDArray
import torch
from torch import Tensor

# Code
backends = [(np, NDArray, "Numpy"), (torch, Tensor, "Torch")]
for backend, dtype, name in backends:
    class f"Class{name}":
        def __init__(self):
            self.output = backend.zeros(1)
        def get_output(self) -> dtype:
            return self.output

# Test
instance_numpy = DiscreteModelNumpy()
print(instance_numpy.get_output())
instance_torch = DiscreteModelTorch()
print(instance_torch.get_output())
```

---

PLEASE READ:

1. If this is bad practice, I need a good reason why.
2. I am trying to do this so I don't need to rewrite code for each backend.

I have tried using the `type` object and similar constructions to the one above; however, with no success.